# Character Identification

Tags: character-identification

What do the following characters say in english.

Forgive me but I can't put them into google translate because it is an image.

[image]

Comment: it is "從昨天"  (since yesterday )

Comment: @TangHo meaning since yesterday something has happened or since yesterday what?

Comment: "Since yesterday" is just a phrase,  not a complete sentence. It can be  "(從昨天開始)就一直下雨" = "It has been raining (since yesterday)" or "(從昨天)到今天"= " (from yesterday) to today"

Comment: in simplified chinese it is 从昨天

Comment: Questions asking for translation of random characters are off topic because they can easily be answered by using a standard Chinese dictionary.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 what about phrases said but not written

Comment: @William - Regardless of audio / written we want to avoid random requests for translation. The aim of the site is to assist language learners. So we want to see why the person wants to know and how they attempted to find the answer. This is to avoid questions like 'what does my friends tattoo say'. With your question above it can be easily answered in 10 seconds using Google's translate app or using a CN dictionary. With audio it would depend on whether someone is asking to translate a random snippet of audio or if they are using it to further their language study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters are 從昨天 - From yesterday/since yesterday.

By itself, it sounds and feels like something is missing.

The song by popular Chinese band S.H.E. - 老婆 Wife, uses it in their lyrics, "**從昨天** 到今天 還有明天. 感謝老天 讓你們 陪在我身邊." (From yesterday, till today, and tomorrow, thank heavens for letting you stay by my side).